# SharedObject for High Score works in PC but not in Air for Android (Mobile)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, shared-objects

I'm using the SharedObject code in ActionScript 3. It works perfectly fine when I publish it on my computer but when I publish it on Air for Android, the high score does not work anymore.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: finally found the solution, when using the the sharedobject, you just have to change this code

var playerHighScore:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myscore");

to this one: 

"myscore" should be changed to the exact apk filename :))

so in my case my apk filename is pandaclash.apk, the sharedobject code should be:

var playerHighScore:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("pandaclash");

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

*i know that `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` also contain' `READ` permission, but as i remember I had the same problem in past which was fixed with it.*

---

i guess **`android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`** is missing
in your appname-app.xml you should make permission's for `SharedObject` like it:

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
        </manifest>
    ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

Comment: thanks for this but apparently the solution was the sharedobject in 

var playerHighScore:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myscore");


"myscore" should be changed to the exact apk filename :))

Answer (score 0):

finally found the solution, when using the the sharedobject, you just have to change this code

```
var playerHighScore:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myscore");
```

to this one:

"myscore" should be changed to the exact apk filename :))

so in my case my apk filename is pandaclash.apk, the sharedobject code should be:

```
var playerHighScore:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("pandaclash");
```